# Bookmark link (OLE_LINK) constnatly breaks in a Word doc stored in OneDrive/SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, onedrive, microsoft-word-2016, sharepoint

In my Word doc I have a "Content Control Drop-down List" and a link to that list that is set to automatically update when the value in the list changes (might be an XY problem, but it's the only solution I found after a day of searching). The link is created via the "Paste Special" dialog.

[image]

You can see in the "Source" field that my Word doc has a SharePoint path because I'm storing it in OneDrive. It's important because I only have this problem with the files in the Cloud, links in local files with local paths work fine.

In short, while I'm working on the doc, everything works fine and the link updates.

[image]

The link breaks as soon as I close the document and open it back up again.

My guess is that the SharePoint link is temporary and it changes each time the document is opened. When the document is stored locally and has a C:\Users... path, the links stay working even after the doc is closed and opened again.

Does anyone have any ideas whether I should be trying to fix this on the SharePoint side and give the doc a permanent link somehow or try and modify the "Source" to point to the local document? Thanks everyone for taking the time.

Edit: I somehow managed to compare the SharePoint links before closing the file and after opening it - they're the same. The link just refuses to update when the source is on SharePoint so I'm not sure what the reason might be anymore. Anyway, I don't think I want to link an item to another item within the same document over the Internet - is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Good question.  I also have issues with Word documents on OneDrive.  For example, when I use "INCLUDETEXT" field, it will also break if I don't run the command in the first moments after opening the document.  This seems to be a bug in Word.

Comment: @MAK thanks for chiming in with a similar issue - I haven't really figured out a solution since asking this question. I've been going down the path of XML mapping: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/cc_var_bm_doc_prop_tools_addin.html. It doesn't create any extra files because the XML schema becomes a part of the .docx file. Most importantly it seems to work fine with OneDrive